# Java - Bounded generic as input to bounded generic method

Tags: java, generics, bounded-wildcard

Given a generic Type `Result<T>` with the following partial implementation

```
public class Result<T> {

    /* fields, ctor, etc... */

    public Result<T> mergeWith(Result<? extends T> other) {
        /* fiddle with this and other (acting as producer) and return */
    }

    /* other methods */

}
```

and the use of it in a Visitor...

Interface:

```
public interface Visitor<T> {

    T visitFile(FileContext ctx);

    T aggregate(T left, T right);

    /* ... */

}
```

Implementation:

```
public class SomeVisitor implements Visitor<Result<? extends Node>> {

    // this works fine, as I can return subtypes of 'Node'
    @Override
    public Result<FileNode> visitFile() { }

    /* ... */

    @Override
    public Result<? extends Node> aggregate(Result<? extends Node> left,
                                               Result<? extends Node> right) {
        // This line completely blows up.
        Result<? extends Node> tempResult = left.mergeWith(right);
        // Expected type: 'Option<? extends capture of ? extends Node>'
        // Have type:     'Option<                     ? extends Node>'
    }
```

Callsite of `SomeVisitor`:

```
FileContext fileCtx = someOtherService.acquireFileContext();
SomeVisitor visitor = new SomeVisitor();
Result<FileNode> fileNodeResult = visitor.visitFile(fileCtx);
// process the result
```

The above example fails with the given type-mismatch error messages.

I have already tried to change the signature of .mergeWith to accept the much narrower `Result<T>` instead of a `Result<? extends T>`. This leads to an expected type of `Result<capture of ? extends Node>` in this example. And breaking it in other places, where `<? extends T>` is the correct generic type, since `other` is a producer in this case.

The only solution that actually works, is casting down both `left` and `right` to `Result<Node>`, merge them and then return:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
Result<Node> tempLeft   = (Result<Node>) left;
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
Result<Node> tempRight  = (Result<Node>) right;
Result<Node> tempResult = tempLeft.mergeWith(tempRight);
```

Not only is that ugly and introduces temp variables, it's also not getting prettier when I inline the casts.

I would like to know if that is just the ugly truth about Java generics and the limit thereof or if I am doing something wrong.

Comment: Can you show the `Visitor.visitFile()` signature? Also, it would help to show how `SomeVisitor` is actually used.

Comment: @shmosel done. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

According to Result's merge declaration you can merge a Result<S> with a Result<T> if and only if T is a subtype of S.

In your aggregate method, left's type parameter is some unknown subclass of Node, and right's type parameter is also some unknown subclass of Node. There's no guarantee that right's type parameter is a subclass of left's.

What if you try this:

```
public <S extends Node, T extends S> Result<? extends Node> aggregate(Result<S> left, Result<T> right) {
    Result<? extends Node> temp = left.mergeWith(right);
    /** do stuff*/
    return temp;
}
```

Here, we declare two types S and T and require that S is a subtype of Node and T is a subtype of S.

Comment: A pretty nifty (yet very Java-y) way of getting around this. Sadly, the interface that I am implementing does describe aggregate as `T aggregate(T left, T right);` Maybe I should augment the question with this info :) Sorry 'bout that!

Comment: Not sure if this is possible without casting... However, it looks like you only need to cast once. tempLeft.mergeWith(right) should be valid.

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes from the `?` captures, which are independent of each other. Don't use `?` captures in class definitions. Use generic type identifiers:

```
public class SomeVisitor<T extends Node> implements Visitor<Result<T>> {

    public Result<FileNode> visitFile() { }

    /* ... */

    protected Result<T> aggregate(Result<T> left, Result<T> right) {
        Result<T> tempResult = left.mergeWith(right);
    }
}
```

Comment: `implements Visitor<Result<T extends Node>>` does not compile, since the bounds of a generic type identifier must be defined on the implementing class, not the interface.

Comment: oops. I'll fix that. I intended to declare the class as `SomeVisitor<T>`